# I need code to send mail fom my Contact Us page

Tags: html, jsp

I have designed a contact form and I need to receive mail from the "Contact Us" page, on a specific email ID.

This my form:

`contact.html`

```
<form action="contactservlet" method="post">
    <h4>Get in  <i>Touch</i></h4>   
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="NAME" class="input-style" />
    <input type="email" id="emailid" name="emailid" placeholder="EMAIl" oninput="sendRequest('GET','Checkemailid',1)" required="required" class="input-style" />
    <input type="text" id="mobno" name="mobno" placeholder="Enter Mobile No." required="required" class="input-style"/>
    <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" required="required" class="input-style"></textarea>
    <div class="contact-btn">
        <a title="" href="#"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't know how to write `contactservlet.java`.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, what have you tried so far and what are the issues you've encountered?

Comment: i have made a contact form , a contactservlet.java , and info is going in database, have a mail.java in package but no mail is being sent

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Try this,

`ContactUs.html`

```
<form action="ContactServlet" method="post">
 <h4>Get in  <i>Touch</i></h4>   
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
 <input type="email" id="emailId" name="emailId" placeholder="Email" />
 <input type="text" id="mobileNo" name="mobileNo" placeholder="Enter Mobile No." />
 <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

For sending mails we used JavaMail API. [Download](http://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/download/javax.mail.jar) and [Documentation](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

`ContactServlet.java -> doPost()`

```
    //This data will be added to your Database using DAO Layer....
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String emailId=request.getParameter("emailId");
    Long mobno=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("mobileNo"));
    String message= request.getParameter("message");
    //Call Some function that do database storage.....

    //Sending Mail Through Gmail SMTP
    //Separate this code at DAO/Service Layer -  -  -
    final String gmailUsername = "somethin@gmail.com";
    final String gmailPassword = "somethin@123";
    try{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(gmailUsername, gmailPassword);
                }
            });
    Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("somethin@gmail.com"));
    mailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(emailId));
    mailMessage.setSubject("Type Subject : ");
    mailMessage.setText("Type LONGGGG Message Here......");

    Transport.send(mailMessage);
    } catch(MessagingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```